# FLutter A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x8c80cf16 (code=1), thread 4219 (flutter-worker-)

Tags: flutter, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing an error when trying to run my flutter app on android 4.4 to 5.0 devices. When app opens it crashes and shows "Unfortunatelly, app has stopped". Logcat is showing
`11-12 12:03:57.826 4203-4219/com.agent.agent_report A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x8c80cf16 (code=1), thread 4219 (flutter-worker-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I builded the app using flutter run --release
When I built it with flutter build apk it worked succesfully.